# Remove specific word from field

Tags: awk

I have file which has some data as below

```
cell   input   out   type   fun
AI20   A1,A2   Z     comb   0 ,((A1,A2))
```

So when ever there is starting 0 in fun column I want to remove that `0 ,`
So my output as

```
cell   input   out   type   fun
AI20   A1,A2   Z     comb   ((A1,A2))
```

I tried code

```
awk '$5~/^0/ {sub(/0 ,/,"",$5)} 1' file
```

But this didn't worked.

Comment: Could you please let us know if there could more than 1 zeros in this one? Or it will be exactly same every time? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: Exactly same every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With shown samples could you please try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/0 ,\(\(/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*,/,"",val)
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  val=""
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/0 ,\(\(/){                ##Using match function to match 0 space (( in line.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)     ##creating val which has sub string of matched regex.
  sub(/.*,/,"",val)                 ##Substituting everything till comma with NULL in val.
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)  ##Printing sub string val and rest of line sub string here.
  val=""                            ##Nullifying val here.
  next                              ##next will skip all statements from here.
}
1                                   ##will print the current line here.
' Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this awk:

```sh
awk -F '[[:blank:]]{3,}' 'NR > 1 { sub(/^0+[, ]*/, "", $NF) } 1' file |
column -t
```

```
cell  input  out  type  fun
AI20  A1,A2  Z    comb  ((A1,A2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in GNU `awk`.
it's possible to set `FS` for removing that `0 ,` you want and  divide the row in two parts, and print it.

```
awk -v FS='.[[:digit:]][[:blank:]]+,'  ' {print $1, $2} '  file
cell   input   out   type   fun
AI20   A1,A2   Z     comb   ((A1,A2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried

```
awk '$5~/^0/ {sub(/0 ,/,"",$5)} 1' file
```

Here $5 is just 0, the comma after that is stored in $6, so you need to remove that as well

Try this.

```
$ awk '$5~/^0/ {sub(/^0/,"",$5); sub(/^,/,"",$6) } 1' neha1.txt | column -t
cell  input  out  type  fun
AI20  A1,A2  Z    comb  ((A1,A2))
```